# Console Command: Area code must be set before starting a session

Tags: magento2, cli, magento-2.1, repositories

I am trying to get a list of orders from the OrderRepository (Magento 2.1) via a console command and am using code as follows...

```
...

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}

public function execute()
{
    $sc = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $items = $this->orderRepository->getList($sc);
}

...
```

This code throws an error of:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException]
Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.

[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
Area code is not set
```

I have attempted to resolve it by passing in the appState (`\Magento\Framework\App\State $appState`) and calling setAreaCode with either `frontend`, `crontab`, `admin` and `adminhtml` - none of which seem to have any effect.

I *have* managed to resolve it by adding an echo at the top of the execute function..

```
public function execute()
{
    echo 'Please please dont throw an exception';
    $sc = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $items = $this->orderRepository->getList($sc);
}
```

Am I missing something glaringly obvious? Or is this a bug in Magento?

Comment: could you post the full class ? specially the declaration of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; it's because in my console script I was calling another class - and because it was to test some code I had been lazy and was calling my class via:

```
$model = $this->objectManager->create('{ns}\{module}\Model\{class}');
$model->execute();
```

It seems doing this throws the area code error up.. with it properly injected and calling `$this->processor->execute();` instead of referencing the Object Mananger directly. Guess this is another negative for using the OM.

In this case I was just implementing a CLI command to test some code; hence the reason for being a little lazy.